# Newly created VMs from gallery image stuck in "Running (Provisioning)" or "Running (Provisioning Timed Out)"

Tags: azure, provisioning

I'm trying to evaluate Azure as a possible platform to move all our servers to, but it hasn't gone well. Alas, I'm in "Free Trial" mode so can't get technical support :(

I'm trying to create some VMs using the "OpenLogic 6.6" standard image. I originally created two through the GUI - one Basic_A1 and one Basic_A0. The Basic_A0 succeeded, but the other one never finished provisioning and never was available. I deleted it and tried again, with the same result.

I found out afterwards that I can't used Reserved IPs on a VM post-creation, so I killed both and started over. I finally got a powershell script to work to create them...however, now BOTH are just spinning in "Running (Provisioning)", where they've been for some time. I expect them to time out. Neither is reachable at the public IP either.

Are things just not working now?

Comment: Sometimes it can take a bit for MS to get things set up.... how long is 'some time'?

Comment: We're talking a couple of hours. One of them is now in "Running (Provisioning Timed Out)" and still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the provisioning events to see if anything went wrong. At portal.azure.com open up your VM blade, and then click the Events tile and check the operations for errors.

[image: Events tile]

Then

[image]

Then click the rows to check the events.

Comment: Both currently say, "No events available" :(

Comment: However, I do see the Status in this portal of one of them as "Failed to create". The other is still "Starting" after several hours. Both appear to be using near 100% CPU

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never got it to work with the standard interface, but with the "preview" portal at portal.azure.com I was able to spin up two VMs fully, with reserved IPs, once I figured out all the things I needed to set up in the new interface to do what I wanted, it created the VMs fine. There was one case where it didn't seem to come up with the IPs it said it did, but a second reboot solved that.